# What does a linux zombie process cost?

Tags: linux, kernel, zombie-process

Just curious. I know that zombie processes cost little resource. But exactly how much? What kind of data structure will be left in memory? Will zombie process incur management overhead for kernel?

Comment: I think the greater concern than memory footprint is using up PIDs. From http://www.howtogeek.com/119815/htg-explains-what-is-a-zombie-process-on-linux/ "Linux systems have a finite number of process IDs – 32767 by default on 32-bit systems." So while zombie processes won't use hardly any memory, they could potentially soak up all available PIDs on a system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the process entry itself is left, waiting for some kind soul to come along and reap it by reading the exit status.